# Analise da maquina/servidor usando o php

Tags: php

Estou a criar um relatório do sistema, sinceramente nao sabia que o PHP fazia isso, pesquisei e descobri que fazia, mas nao achei explicação util, apenas encontrei o PHP SYS INFO como referencia.

Quando digo maquina quero dizer = servidor/pc/maquina onde o sistema ta rodando

Meus pontos de duvidas, seguem esta listagem..

1. Informações de endereço -> IP do servidor, nome de Host
2. Sistema -> Ultimo boot, ativo a quanto tempo, processos ativos e inativos, temperatura da CPU e do 'SYS'
3. Uso da Memoria -> Quanto tem do total, quanto que esta sendo usada

se houver algum artigo, ou orientação para obter isso agradeço.

Answer (score 7):

Considerando que seu servidor PHP é Linux (dificilmente tem instalação de PHP em Windows), como pegar as informações que quer:

- IP: `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`
- Nome do Host: `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`
- Boot mais recente: `shell_exec('uptime')` ou ler o arquivo `/proc/uptime` que contém 2 valores. O 1o é o Uptime em segundos
- Processos ativos e inativos: `shellexec('ps -eF')` processar a saída de acordo com suas necessidades.
- Temperatura

  ```
  $temp    = exec('lm_sensors | grep \'°\'');
  $tempr   = explode('+', $temp);
  $tempval = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $tempr[1]);
  ```
- Memória sendo usada: `memory_get_usage(true)` (para o seu script PHP)
- Memória total sendo usada no servidor: faça um parse da saída do comando `free` (contrib. @GuilhermeNascimento)
- Memória total: ler o arquivo `/proc/meminfo`

Edição com base no comentário de @GuilhermeNascimento:

"para que lm-sensors funcione, o servidor tem que ter instalado ele e geralmente servidores SHARED não se pode instalar por conta própria (talvez o servidor possua ou não instalado)."

Comment: Uma boa resposta, porém existem 3 problemas, primeiro `memory_get_usage` não pega a quantidade de memória no servidor, mas sim do script executado, segundo `lm_sensors` em seu código é uma constante e não um string e terceiro para que lm-sensors funcione, o servidor tem que ter instalado ele e geralmente servidores SHARED não se pode instalar por conta própria (talvez o servidor possua ou não instalado).

Comment: Sobre o lm_sensors, corrigi o código. Quando a não existir lm_sensors no servidor, se não existir não tem como a pessoa ter acesso a esse dados. A menos que exista outro método de acesso que eu não conheço. Se vc sabe outro jeito de acessar esses dados, pf inclua a resposta que também me auxilia. Quanto à memória sendo utilizada, no meu entendimento foi isso que ele pediu. Quanto de memória o script dele está utilizando para que possa ver se tem algum lugar no código que está consumindo memória demais. Mas incluí o método para obter a memória total sendo usada no servidor. Grato pelo auxílio.

Comment: Não disse sobre outros métodos, o que vc tem é que passar esses detalhes na resposta, que as vezes é necessário instalar algumas coisas, pois esses comando não são nativos do PHP.

Comment: Acredito que seu comentário já é suficiente para esclarecer esse assunto. :)

Comment: *SE* a pessoa ler os comentários :)

Comment: Pronto @GulhermeNascimento. Ficou bom ? :) Se ainda não estiver diga aí o que acrescentar mais. Estou no espírito de ano novo :D

Comment: Sim esta muito bom, não quero dar ordem em ninguém rs, só queria ajudar a melhorar a sua resposta, que já era muito boa! Parabéns! +1

Comment: :) eu sei tbém tava só brincando. Abraço e feliz ano novo.

Answer (score 7):

Existe um projeto interessante no GitHub que nos permite obter um "universo" de informações sobre o sistema:

## [phpSysInfo](http://phpsysinfo.github.io/phpsysinfo/)

Uma grande vantagem é o suporte que obtemos pois o projeto está testado em [inúmeras plataformas](https://github.com/phpsysinfo/phpsysinfo):

> • Linux 2.6.x
>   • FreeBSD 7.x
>   • OpenBSD 2.8+
>   • NetBSD
>   • DragonFly
>   • IBM AIX
>   • HP-UX
>   • Darwin/OSX
>   • Win 2000 / Win 2003 / Win XP / Win Vista / Win 7 / Win 8 / Win 8.1
>   • > PHP 5.2 or later ◦With PCRE, XML, XSL, MBString and SimpleXML extension.

### Instalação

O processo de instalação é relativamente simples mas carece dois pontos de atenção em baixo descritos junto com as notas de instalação:

1. Descompactar o código fonte que pode ser [descarregado aqui](https://github.com/phpsysinfo/phpsysinfo/releases/) para a raiz do servidor.
2. Na pasta existe um arquivo de configuração chamado `phpsysinfo.ini.new`, se a instalação que está a ser feita é uma instalação nova, deve-se copiar este arquivo para `phpsysinfo.ini` e editá-lo:

   ```
   cp phpsysinfo.ini.new phpsysinfo.ini
   ```
3. Realizar as seguintes verificações no arquivo `php.ini` do servidor:

   - Verificar se a entrada `include_path` contém `.`
   - Como o phpSysInfo requer acesso a muitos arquivos no `/proc` entre outros, é importante ter o `safe_mode` desativado:

     Para o efeito no arquivo `php.ini`, alterar a linha do `safe_mode` para:

     ```
     safe_mode = Off
     ```

   Por fim, garantir que está instalada a extensão de PHP com o nome [`php-xml`](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php), sendo a mesma necessária para um correto funcionamento do phpSysInfo.

Se tiverem sido realizadas alterações no arquivo `php.ini`, basta reiniciar o servidor e pronto, pode começar a diversão.

**Nota:** Para localizar o arquivo `php.ini` no servidor, a partir da linha de comandos podemos usar o seguinte comando:

```
find / -name php.ini -print
```

### Demonstração

Existe uma demonstração online multi-língua que demonstra as inúmeras potencialidades deste projeto:

http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/phpsysinfo/index.php?disp=dynamic

[image: Captura de tela do link em cima]

<sup>E muito muito mais...</sup>

### Formato dos dados

Os dados podem também ser extraídos através da API no formato que se adequa ao que pretendemos fazer:

- XML <sup>[ver exemplo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/phpsysinfo/xml.php?plugin=complete)</sup>

  ```
  /phpsysinfo/xml.php?plugin=complete
  ```
- JSON <sup>[ver exemplo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/phpsysinfo/xml.php?plugin=complete&json)</sup>

  ```
  /phpsysinfo/xml.php?plugin=complete&json
  ```
- JSONP <sup>[ver exemplo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/phpsysinfo/xml.php?plugin=complete&jsonp&callback=getData)</sup>

  ```
  /phpsysinfo/xml.php?plugin=complete&jsonp&callback=getData
  ```

Comment: Ótima resposta +1